# How to find an Element in Watin by its tag name?

Tags: .net, watin

How to find a specific element, or a list of elements by using their TagName using Watin?

Comment: What do you mean by TagName?  You mean a div or a textarea?

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you would like to be able to do?

Answer (score 10):

As of WatiN 2.0 beta 1 this has changed to:

```
ie.ElementWithTag("h1", constraint);
```

Constraints are created when using the Find.XXX methods.

Here is an example:

```
ie.ElementWithTag("h1", Find.ByClass("blue"));
```

Comment: Could you expand this example to show what is in the constraint object?

Comment: Constraints are created when using the Find.XXX methods. Here is an example:
ie.ElementWithTag("h1", Find.ByClass("blue");

Answer (score 1):

For example, to find the first <h1> on a page, use:

```
ie.Element("h1", Find.ByIndex(0))
```

Comment: I -1, because this is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me:

> var element = ie.Element(x => x.Text == "[innerText]" && x.TagName == "[tagname]");

Comment: Be aware that you are iterating over all the elements in the page, where as ElementWithTag(tagname, constaint) only iterates over the elements with the given tagname.