# Watin: Search in children of an element

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, watin

I want to do a "two step" search using Watin. For example I would like to search for a ul-tag having class "abc". Then I would like to search for a certain li-tag inside that element. The code might look like this:

```
ie.ElementWithTag("ul", Find.ByClass("abc")).ElementsWithTag("li", Find.ByXYZ());
```

But Element does not have an ElementWithTag method. Any hint how to do that with Watin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors of Watin told me that this will be supported in the next version. At the moment this can be done using filter and lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

---

**UPDATE**

Actually I just saw info that there is ie.ElementWithTag now, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389066/how-to-find-an-element-in-watin-by-its-tag-name) question.
So maybe rest of this post won't be that helpful

---

Don't have ready solution for you, but maybe a starting point.
Some (long) time ago I was writing some automation script for one page. I used powershell but it should be easy to migrate to C# (which I assume you use).

So in this part of script I' searching on page element that has tag *input* and is named *Save Changes*.

```
    #getting property from com object::IHTMLDOMAttribute
    function getProperty ([System.__ComObject] $obj, [string] $prop)
    {
        [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember($prop, [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, $obj, $null)
    }



    $ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application";


    $ie.visible = $true;
    $ie.navigate("http://mytestpage.com");
    $doc = $ie.Document;

 $saveButton = $null;
 $inputElts = $null;
 $inputElts = $doc.getElementsByTagName('input')
 foreach ($elt in $inputElts)
 {
     $a = $elt.getAttributeNode('value')
  if ($a -and (getProperty $a 'nodeValue') -eq 'Save changes')
     {
         $saveButton = $elt;
   break;
     }
 }
```

So If you would replace part in loop that looks for Save Changes property of element (and delete getProperty declaration) with check for proper class  than it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented in their new version 2.0.50.11579.

[Watin 2.0.50.11579](http://watin.org/documentation/release-2-0-50-11579/)